# Distribution difference between Kotlin Random and Java Random

Tags: java, kotlin, random

Considering the following code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.newFixedThreadPoolContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet
import java.util.Random

val ids = ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>()

fun append(id: String) {
    if (ids.contains(id)) throw RuntimeException("Repeated: $id")
    ids.add(id)
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val rnd = Random(System.nanoTime())
    delay(1000)

    val scope = CoroutineScope(newFixedThreadPoolContext(32, "MyThread"))
    repeat(10_000_000) {
        scope.launch {
            val high = rnd.nextLong()
            val low = rnd.nextLong()

            append("$high:$low")
        }
    }

    scope.coroutineContext[Job]?.children?.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

Running on MacOS 10.14.6, Kotlin 1.3 and JVM 1.8, I could not produce any repeated id. However, after replacing `import java.util.Random` with `import kotlin.random.Random`, I am able to produce repeated id almost immediately (after 25000 generation). Is this something expected regarding to `XorWow` algorithm?

Comment: Ok, looking at the implementation, XorWowRandom implementation in Kotlin should not be used in multi threaded envs

Comment: So, Java Random is thread safe however it performs poorly across multiple threads because of synchronizations. Kotlin XorWow implementation is NOT thread safe. So do not use it in multiple thread scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was subtle. as of kotlin 1.3, `Random(seed)` factory function, returns a `XorWow` implementation which is not the same as Java implementation. This implementation is NOT thread-safe at all. So, do not use a single instance of `XorWowRandom` shared across multiple threads.